# c++ program does not show output

Tags: c++

code to print
A
B B
C C C
D D D D
E E E E E

```
 #include<iostream>

using namespace std;


 int main() { 
     int j = 70;
     char ch = ' ';
     int k = 65;
     int n = j - k;
     for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) { 
         for(int m = 1; m <= i; m++) {
             ch=(char)(k);    
             cout<<(k+"  ");      
         }
         cout<<endl;
         k++;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

please identify the error in my code which i am running  on linux(ubuntu)

Comment: Please fix your indentation, this is needlessly difficult to read.

Comment: Prefer to use character literals, like `'A'`, instead of their decimal ASCII equivalents.  The `'A'` can easily be converted to an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

`+` is a binary add operator, so when you do `(k+"  ")`  you are literally adding `65,66,67,68 and 69` to pointer address of `" "` (string literal) in a loop.
Which is undefined behavior.

Hence replace your

```
     cout<<(k+"  ");
```

with

```
      cout<<ch<<"  ";
```

Comment: This answer would be more complete if you explained why they should replace tha tline.

Comment: @Borgleader Ok!

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the line `cout<<(k+"  ");`
To explain what is happening let's consider `k = 2` and the const char [] `"bacd"`.
Then `2 + "bacd"` is same as having a character pointer from second position of "bacd".
So `cout << k + "bacd";` will print `cd` as output.

So `k+"  "` is equivalent to a **character pointer from kth position of "  "**

Answer (score -5):

The error is in this line:

```
         cout<<(k+"  ");
```

Comment: You should probably explain why that line is an error and a possible solution

Comment: Perhaps I should, but first can you tell me if I really had to edit the code to fix indentation?